# How to save Items in Local Storage with specific ID

Tags: javascript, local-storage, blogs

I am practicing blog stuff. posting and deleting posts. mini social media I can say. And I wanted to save posts on localStorge. however I could save only 1 post at a time. and then I wanted to do it with IDs.

I create id with random number generator:

```
let newId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 100000) + 100000)
let postContents = {
    ID : newId,
    text: value,
}
```

an then I upload those values in `let storedPosts = []` array.
then I save it to local storage with JSON:

```
let toJson = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('storedPosts', JSON.stringify(storedPosts));
}
```

and then I get it from Local Storage:

```
let storedJsonPosts = localStorage.getItem('storedPosts')
let storedPosts_toUpload = JSON.parse(storedJsonPosts)
```

and then I join these two arrays together:

```
let storedPostsArray = storedPosts.concat(storedPosts_toUpload)
```

and after this I don't know what to do. I tried this:

```
let uploadStoredPosts = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < storedPostsArray.length; i++) {
        let post = document.createElement('div')
        $post_place.appendChild(post)

        let text = document.createElement('p')
        post.appendChild(text)
        text.textContent = storedPostsArray[i].text
    }
}
```

but it showed this:

[image]

It couldn't reach array values. plz help

Comment: You only got 5 Mb of storage with localstorage. If you use localforage, you can save up to 25% of the hard drive (if I recall correclty) AND can save arrays and objects. https://github.com/localForage/localForage

Comment: @RickardElimää well I'm just practicing and trying to learn new skills. It doesn't matter for me tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you're after?

The code reads from localStorage, parses that information, returns an empty array if it's the first time the user posted, pushes a new value to the array, stores that array by stringifying it, and the appending the new value to the document.

If you want the page to read from localStorage on page load, you need to add a function that reads from localStorage, and then loops through all posts to add each one of them by using `appendToDocument()`.

StackOverflow doesn't allow the use of localStorage, so I used a variable for demo purposes.

I left out id as a property. You can play around with that by yourself, but I would suggest to use a timestamp as a foreign key ("id").

```js
var justForDemoPurpose = null;

const addPostBtn = document.getElementById("add-button");
const addPostInput = document.getElementById("add-post");
const postContainerEl = document.getElementById("post-container");

addPostBtn.addEventListener('click', addPost);

function readFromLocalStorage(key) {
  let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(justForDemoPurpose);
  // let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

  console.log('returning items:', localStorageItem);
  
  return localStorageItem;
}

function storeInLocalStorage(key, value) {
  justForDemoPurpose = JSON.stringify(value);
  // JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem(key, value));
}

function addPost() {
  let postValue = addPostInput.value;
  
  if (postValue) {
    const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'posts';    
    let storedPosts = readFromLocalStorage(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY) || [];

    storedPosts.push(postValue);
    storeInLocalStorage(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, storedPosts);
    
    appendToDocument(postValue);
  }
}

function appendToDocument(postValue) {
    let divEl = document.createElement('div')
    divEl.textContent = postValue;
    
    postContainerEl.appendChild(divEl);
}
```

```html
<div class="addPostContainer">
  <input id="add-post" placeholder="Type here"> <button id="add-button">Add Post</button>
</div>

<section id="post-container"></section>
```

Comment: on 11th line in js code, localStorageItem is already declared when we remove comment. can you fix it?

Comment: You need to remove the line above it, just like you need to remove the line in `storeInLocalStorage`. As stated in the post, it's just there for demo purposes because SO doesn't allow to use localStorage.